# I want html button to open contact form and then redirecting to the link

Tags: html, wordpress

I have HTML button. It is redirected to dropbox download. I want that when click this button, a contact form pop up with email to enter. After entering the email it should go to that drop box link. All I want is the contact form just before going to the redirecting link. Website is in wordpress. Or is there any plugin which can help me?

Here is the code :

```
[button download_link link="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pybcfpdd46cr4xc/AABrY7b91uIwPCmcNJAUvmvsa/Aquila_Ventures_Gold.pdf" size="medium" target = "blank"]Read more[/button]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go with this flow -

1) user clicks on "read more"

2) "read more" button has a code to open a pop up asking for email (compulsory field) and a submit button. 
check code for popup form here http://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/

3) user enters email and hits "submit".

4) put your drop box file download code on the "submit" button.